# Conflict std::set and NTL::vec_ZZ

Tags: c++, ntl

I am trying to use std::set for arbitrary-length integer vectors defined from the NTL-Library and for some reason it doesn't work. It works totally fine with the ZZ integers defined by the library:

```
#include <NTL/ZZ.h>
#include <NTL/vec_ZZ.h>
#include <set>

NTL_CLIENT

int main(void){


    std::set<ZZ> foo;
    foo.insert(to_ZZ(1)); //works without problems

    std::set<vec_ZZ> vectorFoo;
    vec_ZZ vec;
    vectorFoo.insert(vec);  //causes compiler to crash

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know why the first insertion works and the second doesn't?

Comment: Standard Library containers usually have a requirement that there elements be copy constructible and assignable, I am not sure if same is the case with the lib you use, but seems like the second usage doesn't obey the rule.

Comment: Ah, OK, that could be. I can use vec_ZZ with list or vector, just not with set....

Comment: Causes compiler to crash?! Is there an error message? I imagine vec_ZZ needs to have a comparison operator defined.

Comment: Yes, the error message is /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_function.h:230: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’  . So I need to tell set how to compare two vectors? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::set<T>` is ordered by `std::less<T>`, which defaults to `bool operator<(T,T)`. `ZZ` does define a proper `operator<` (they're ordered) but `vec_ZZ` doesn't. In fact, most NTL classes don't, not even `ZZ_p`. Therefore `std::set<ZZ_p>` is equally invalid.